# Facebook API unknown exception with api call after login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

after successful facebook login we get an exception:

**Fatal error: Uncaught GraphMethodException: API calls from the server require an appsecret_proof argument thrown in .../.../lib/base_facebook.php on line 1238**

The code is:

```
$user = $facebook -> getUser();
if(!$user) {
 //redirect etc. stuff here
}
else {
 $me = $facebook -> api("/me"); //we get the exception here
}
```

Anyone seen similar error? I cant find any info on this error anywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16765164/694061), this appsecret_proof thing was added to the latest version of PHP SDK quite recently. So my guess is that your App Setting for appsecret_proof is enabled, but you are not using the latest version of PHP SDK so the appcesret_proof is not generated.
You might want to check your setting at App Dashboard > Setting > Advanced > Security.

[image]

EDIT: 2013-08-09
Now they have [official document][3].

Answer (score 1):

I got similar error to you. And I don't know how too. But if you don't really need OAuth login. You can disable it in setting>advance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Facebook Developer site - Open application setting - Advanced setting and disable these two things.
1) Require AppSecret Proof for Server API calls:
2) Stream post URL security:

Worked for me :)