# No documentation about AppSecret Proof for Server API calls?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, call, server-side

If I enable the option giving in **Advanced Settings** is gives me **BAD Request or error code 400**

If I enable this option, what is the required value of AppSecret_Proof parameter?

Comment: Did you find the answer to this? I'm hitting the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you visit github and have a look at their PHP SDK's [code](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php), you'll find how they generate appsecret_proof's value.

[image]

This part was recently added so you have to refer to the latest version of PHP SDK. To activate/inactivate, as you already know, you have to visit App Dashboard > Setting > Advanced.

EDIT: 2013-08-09
Now they have [official document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/securing-graph-api/).

Comment: Thanks, it helped to resolve the latest FB Login issue on my server.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation article [Securing Graph API Requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/securing-graph-api/):

> The app secret proof is a sha256 hash of your access token, using the app secret as the key. Here's what the call looks like in PHP:
>
> ```
> $appsecret_proof = hash_hmac('sha256', $access_token, $app_secret);
> ```