# Facebook API - Get Comment with php sdk error?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have tried to get facebook comments, but always displays `{"data":[]}` , but in tools graph explorer, work perfectly

i'm using **php-sdk**

this my code

```
<?php
require 'inc/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxx',
  'secret' => 'xxx',
  'cookie'  => true,
  ));
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if($user) { 
    $get = $facebook->api("/807642829246790/comments","GET");
    print_r($get);  
} else {
    header("Location:".$facebook->getLoginUrl());
}
?>
```

so, what wrongs above code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using the app token instead of user token. Try copying the token directly from graph explorer and use it to instantiate a new FB instance. Then retrieve comments from that instance. You would see the results as seen in graph explorer.

Comment: can you give me example, how to add token using php sdk ? i tried `api("/807642829246790/comments","GET",array('access_token'=>$token));` but still error

Comment: error `Uncaught GraphMethodException: Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument thrown in`

Comment: @user3566810 see this and let me know if it doesn't work - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669250/facebook-api-unknown-exception-with-api-call-after-login

Comment: same as above, but when using `https://graph.facebook.com/807642829246790/comments?access_token=xxxx` work perfectly

Comment: @user3566810 Yes, that is direct http request. You can do that and bypass API calls. But the intention here is that you need to use user token instead of app token. Here you are using the token copied from graph explorer, right?

Comment: great, you can get this token from your code, read more in the docs - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/ Please accept the answer if it helped.